# Pick random Element of an Array Actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, actionscript, random

I have an array of movieclips and i want to put them on stage. so they have to be unique and randomly chosen.

how can I do that?

thank you for your time

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can get a random number using `Math.random()` This will return a number between 0 and 1.

So, for getting a random element of the array, use this:

```
function getRandomElementOf(array:Array):Object {
    var idx:int=Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
    return array[idx];
}
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer, but how can I put them on the satge?
i have tried with addChild(array[idx]) but is not working;

Comment: `stage.addChild(getRandomElementOf(movieClipArray));` or `stage.addElement(getRandomElementOf(movieClipArray));`

Comment: You will need to have already set the `x` and `y` properties of the movieclips before adding (or you can even do it after adding)

Comment: i have the x and y of the mc`s

var min_x:Number = stage.x - 2 * (breite / 4) - 50;
   var max_x:Number = stage.x - (breite / 4) - 50;
   var mid_x:Number = stage.x - 50;
   var min_y:Number = 0;
   var max_y:Number = hoehe / 2;
   var mid_y:Number = hoehe;


   var n:uint = array1.length;
   for (var i:uint = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
    var mc:MovieClip = array1[i];
    mc.x = Math.round(Math.random() * (max_x - min_x) + min_x);
    mc.y = Math.round(Math.random() * (max_y - min_y) + min_y);

   }

Comment: It works perfectly... I have tried using addChild and it is all fine

Comment: If the movie-clips are library items, have you exported them fir ActionScript in the properties dialog?

Comment: yes it works thank you!
I am using this mc's as puzzle pieces bcause I want to make a puzzle game.
I made the grid, too and now I want to make the solution of the game like when all the mc's are in the right order the whole bitmap image should be displayed.
do you have any ideea how I can do that?

Comment: i made the grid with the draw function and I used it in a loop. 
the second question is how can i make the mc's to automatically position themselves when I drop them on one of the grid part?
thank you for your time

Comment: First, you are going to have to check the mouse coordinates. Then using `switch` statements, find out which grid part the mouse is in. Then, set x and y of the puzzle part so that it moves to the correct position in the grid

Comment: Math.floor() is unnecessary in the code above. Typecasting a Number to an int already truncates it to a whole integer. A uint would probably be better also.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an `Array` already, you should be able to define a random sort, then you can add them to the stage as needed.

```
//get your array as needed...
var myArray:Array = getYourMovieClipsArray();

//randomize it by "sorting" it...
myArray.sort(randomSort);

//do something with them...
for(var i:int=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
    addChild(myArray[i]);
}



//sorting function
public function randomSort(objA:Object, objB:Object):int{
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 2) - 1;
}
```

Comment: why to sort and re-arrange array when you can just get a random index ?

Comment: I presumed the comment about "unique" in the OP's question indicated he wanted to ensure that the clips were not pulled out multiple times.  If desired, you could create an array of indexes to match the movie clip array... randomize the array of indexes... then pluck from the randomized list 1 at a time until finished to ensure no duplicates.