# AS3 random algorithm

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3

I need a suggestion. I want to have a function that returns random numbers from let say 1 to 100, with condition to not repeat the chosen number. It is something like chess table that will be filled with something random and not one thing over another thing... If someone can tell a suggestion I'll be very happy. Thanks.

Comment: [How to generate a random number from 1 to 100 only once?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18716071/1696720)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `Array` of 100 numbers (1..100), then 'sort' the Array by 'random'. You can then pull out the numbers one at a time working your way through the array.

I haven't tested the code below but I had these snippets available that you could piece together to achieve the intended result.

```
public static function randomNumber(min:Number, max:Number):Number{
    var rnd:Number = Math.floor((Math.random()*((max+1)-min))+min);
    return rnd;
}

public static function randomize(arr:Array):Array{
    var len:Number = arr.length;
    var rnd:Number;
    var tmp:Object;
    for(var i:Number=0;i<len;i++){
        rnd = randomNumber(0,(len-1));
        tmp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[rnd];
        arr[rnd] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
}

var setOfNumbers:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int=0;i<100;i++){
    setOfNumbers[i] = (i+1);
}
var shuffledSetOfNumbers:Array = randomize(setOfNumbers);
```

*Notes:*

- For the purists this "randomizing" isn't "truly" random (if you're writing a Card shuffler for a Vegas gambling machine you'll want to use something different - [case in point!](http://www.cigital.com/papers/download/developer_gambling.php))
- My `randomNumber` and `randomize` functions above are `static` as I've typically included them that way in the apps I've needed them but you don't have to use it this way
- My original lib used `Number` vs `int` or `uint` for some of the variables for more options when used but feel free to clean that up

Comment: It's work perfectly but I don't understand what are you doing in the randomize for. If you want to explain a little.  Thank you.

Comment: If you can explain how it's work with small array, let's say 5 items.

Comment: @tziuka the `randomize` function takes an array of "things" (in your case numbers (but it could be users, items, cards, shapes, etc.). It determines the length of the array then loops over that length swapping a random item in the list for the current index. It isn't perfect but it will certainly mix up the items in the list.

Comment: We used to do something very similiar, except we would add a "rdm" property to the object in the array, and then actually use Array.sort("rdm")  Not sure if it's worth a new answer or not.

Comment: @Bob it's funny you mention that as I just checked and I have a previous answer that takes a similar approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913412/pick-random-element-of-an-array-actionscript-3/12477306#12477306

Comment: This is common "shuffling" code, but incorrect.  Quick proof:  let `n=len`.  Each time thru the loop, one of `n` random numbers is used.  The loop goes around `n` times, so in all there are `n^n` (`n` to the `n`'th power) possible swap sequences.  But `n^n` isn't generally divisible by `n!` (factorial(n) = the number of possible permutations).  Therefore some permutations are **necessarily** favored over others by this code.  Not for n=2 (2! divides 2^2), but generally for n>2 (e.g., 3!=6 does not divide 3^3=27).

Comment: See [Fisher-Yates shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for a correct way to shuffle.  The code needed isn't more complicated, but is crucially different ;-)

Answer (score 1):

also like that...

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Vadym Gordiienko
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            var startArray:Array = generateNumberArray(100);
            var randomArray:Array = randomArray(startArray);
            trace("startArray = " + startArray);
            trace("randomArray = " + randomArray);
        }
        /**
         * generate Array of numbers by length
         * @param   length
         * @return Array of numbers
         */
        public static function generateNumberArray(length:int):Array 
        {
            var numberArray:Array = [];
            for (var i:int = 0; i < length; i++) 
            {
                numberArray[i] = i+1;
            }

            return numberArray;
        }

        /**
         * generate randomly mixed array by input array
         * @param   inputArray - simple not mixed array
         * @return Array - mixed array
         */
        public static function randomArray(inputArray:Array):Array 
        {
            var randomArray:Array = [];
            var tempArray:Array = [];
            for (var i:int = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) 
            {
                tempArray.push(inputArray[i]);
            }
            while (tempArray.length)
            {
                var randomNumber:int = Math.round(Math.random() * (tempArray.length - 1));// get random number of left array
                randomArray.push( tempArray[randomNumber] );
                tempArray.splice(randomNumber, 1); // remove randomed element from temporary aarray
            }
            tempArray = null;
            delete [tempArray];

            return randomArray;
        }

    }

}
```